# cisco Switch Stack Query

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, switching

Just a small question can we stack poe and non poe switch (2960x)suppose we have 2 non poe and 2 poe switch , then can we stack this
Can we make stack of 4

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is no issue with stacking PoE and non-PoE switches.  The biggest trick is to know which ports are PoE and which are not--if they are the same speed then you will have to rely on commands like `show inventory` and `show power inline` to keep track of the PoE ports.   Also, watch your power readings (and add redundant power depending on the model).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. I am pretty sure they can be different models as long as they are running the same IOS.

Jack.